# How do I tell Flow that there will be a class on window without explicitly specifying its type?

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I want to incorporate the Google Maps JS library into a Flow-typed project. Since there aren't any remotely complete Flow externs for the library, I'd like to tell Flow to accept whatever methods and constants I call from the class as `Function` and `any`, respectively. I know that the best answer would be to write a complete extern for GMaps and post it on Github, but I've got deadlines to meet. Using flow-typed is also an option to generate stubs, but that only seems to work on npm packages. What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely skip checks, you can simply declare:

`declare var google: any;`

Which will allow you to do whatever you want to `google`:

```
google.maps.Map();
google();
google.maps.Map.call();
```

Or if you wanted to at least ensure you always call `google.maps.something` and never `google` by itself:

`declare var google: { maps: Object };`